# Parsing social media posts in dart

Tags: string, dart, parsing

I need to parse the body of social media posts but am struggling with how to parse including all corner cases

Here is some sample code of my class model, an example containing all corner cases, and the expected correct result.

### Main:

```dart
void main() {
  const String testPostBody = '''
  Hello this is normal text#flutter #dart\n\n@flutter @dart\nhttps://flutter.dev\n\n
  ''';

  List<BodyComponent> correctResult = [
    NormalText('Hello this is normal text'),
    Hashtag('#flutter'),
    NormalText(' '),
    Hashtag('#dart'),
    NormalText('\n\n'),
    Mention('@flutter'),
    NormalText(' '),
    Mention('@dart'),
    NormalText('\n'),
    Link('https://flutter.dev'),
    NormalText('\n\n'),
  ];
}
```

### Simplified class model:

- `BodyComponent`

```dart
abstract class BodyComponent {
  final String rawText;

  BodyComponent(this.rawText);

  String get text;
}
```

- `NormalText`

```dart
class NormalText extends BodyComponent {
  NormalText(String rawText) : super(rawText);

  @override
  String get text => rawText;
}
```

- `Hashtag`

```dart
class Hashtag extends BodyComponent {
  Hashtag(String rawText) : super(rawText);

  @override
  String get text => rawText;
}
```

- `Mention`

```dart
class Mention extends BodyComponent {
  Mention(String rawText) : super(rawText);

  @override
  String get text => rawText;
}
```

- `Link`

```dart
class Link extends BodyComponent {
  Link(String rawText) : super(rawText);

  @override
  String get text => rawText;
}
```

I am struggling to write a parse function that outputs the correct output in `main`